# Unable to load javascript library with requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I keep getting the following errors, regardless of the timeout setting:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: ko is not defined knockout.activity.js:381
>   Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules: knockout
>   http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeout

```
var require = {
    baseUrl: "/app1/script",

    paths: {
        jquery: "lib/jquery/jquery-1.8.3",
        knockout: "lib/knockout/knockout-2.2.0",
        activity: "lib/knockout/knockout.activity"
    },

    shim: {
        "activity": {
            deps: [
                "jquery",
                "knockout"
            ],
            exports: "ko"
        } 
    }
};
```

and in my view model:

```
define([
    "jquery",
    "knockout",
    "activity",
],

function ($, ko) {
```

Comment: have you tried without the baseUrl? and I believe that you also need to provide a 'parameter' for `activity` in the view function, not 100% sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Export activity as jQuery.fn.activity.

If you look at the source for knockout.activity.js, it's expecting ko to be defined as the KnockoutJS object. But you broke that by defining knockout.activity.js as ko.

Have a look at this: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim

Comment: so,  exports: "jQuery.fn.activity"?

Comment: Are you sure the paths are correct? Use the network tab in the WebKit developer tool to verify you're fetching the scripts via the correct paths. BaseUrl also applies to jQuery and knockout.

Comment: All the scripts are loaded according to the network tab, but it still says ko is undefined (even though knockout library is loaded).  ko exists on window.ko, but not this.ko...

Comment: Why do you need to use this.ko? Knockout is defined as a global object and should be used as such.

Comment: Yes you are right, I just need to remove it from the callback signature

Answer (score -1):

change the name from knockout to ko in your require

```
define([
    "jquery",
    "ko",
    "activity",
],

function ($, ko) {
```

ko is the root namespace not "knockout".